# (pass "all" in parameter ?) | how can I make parameter ? in WHERE filter to be a return of ALL in sql request

Tags: c#, sql, parameter-passing

*I am making a wpf C# app following MVVM.
It processes data from accdb (with several connected tables) using DataSet via ServerExplorer.
I am trying to make a filtered search right now.*

```
        SELECT        IDBug, [Date], ReportedBy, Replicated, ReproducableSteps, AppArea, Status, FixedVer, FixedBy, Notes, Title
        FROM            Bugs
        WHERE      ([Date] >=  ?)
        AND ([Date] <= ?) 
        AND (Status = ?)
        AND (AppArea = ?)
        AND (Replicated = ?)
        AND (ReportedBy =  ?)
```

This was working, but only if use all the filter settings.

```
        int idAr = (from DataRow dr in ars.GetData().Rows
                                        where (string)dr["Area"] == AreaSe.ToString()
                                        select (int)dr["IDArea"]).FirstOrDefault();
        

        int idCust = (from DataRow dr in custs.GetData().Rows
                                          where (string)dr["CustomerName"] == CustomS.ToString()
                                          select (int)dr["IDCustomer"]).FirstOrDefault();


        BugTable = bugs.GetT(StartDate, StopDate, State, idAr, replicationS, idCust);
```

I do have some null values in my data, that is why I tried to do smth similar to

> WHERE Title = ? OR (? IS NULL))

instead of

> WHERE Title = ?

for each of the parameters. But it messes up the data types...

I don`t think that is smart to write a different sql query for each case, so I need to know how cann I pass "SELECT ALL" to a ? parameter.

Comment: Use Dynamic SQL to add the extra filtering predicate as needed. Alternatively, you can use the `OR` trick as shown by @viveknuna below that will work well for small tables; however, it does have significant performance implications when used with medium-sized (or big) tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do use `case` in `where` clause like this. You can pass `null` as default value for the parameter.

So it will return the records for `@param` if it is not passed else it will return all records.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2….
FROM TableName 
WHERE ColName = CASE WHEN @param IS NULL THEN ColName ELSE @param END
```

Comment: Can you please try to give me an example with comparison sign WHERE      ([Date] >=  ?)         AND ([Date] <= ?)

Comment: It should be similar like WHERE @parameter IS NULL OR Date > = @parameter;

Comment: VisualStudio TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard detects unrecognized keyword WHEN...

Comment: SELECT        IDBug, [Date], ReportedBy, Replicated, ReproducableSteps, AppArea, Status, FixedVer, FixedBy, Notes, Title
FROM            Bugs
WHERE        
([Date] =CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN [Date] ELSE [Date] =>? END) 
AND ([Date]  =CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN [Date] ELSE  [Date] =< ? END) 
AND (Status = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN Status ELSE ? END) 
AND (AppArea = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN AppArea ELSE ? END) 
AND (Replicated = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN Replicated ELSE ? END)
AND (ReportedBy = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN ReportedBy ELSE ? END)

Comment: I suspect I do it the wrong way

Comment: You need to use parameter name in place of `?`